# vim substitutes with cursor keeping its position

Tags: vim, substitution, text-cursor

I wish vim to remove all trailing spaces automatically keeping the cursor in its current position, so I use the following autocmd in my vimrc

```
autocmd BufWritePre *
\ exec "%s/\\s\\+$//e" | exec 'normal ``'
```

It works well normally. But if nothing is changed since last writing, a 'w' command will lead the cursor move to the last position when last writing is executed. What should I do if I wish the cursor keep its position unconditionally.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the command `silent!` to avoid the error caused by the failed match from affecting the rest of your command:

```
exec "silent! %s/\\s\\+$//e" | exec 'normal ``'
```

See `:help silent`.

Answer (score 1):

You can manually set the mark first via `:normal! m'`, but it's better to save the entire *view*, as jumping back to the mark just restores the cursor position, but not necessarily the entire view inside the window (in case scrolling occurred).

```
autocmd BufWritePre *
\ let g:saveview = winsaveview() |
\ %s/\s\+$/e" |
\ call winrestview(g:saveview)
```

This still suffers from clobbering your search pattern (which wrapping in a `:function` could fix).

I would recommend to use a tested and more configurable plugin instead. Coincidentally, I've developed the [DeleteTrailingWhitespace plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3967) that can do automatic, unconditional deletion via the following configuration:

```
let g:DeleteTrailingWhitespace = 1
let g:DeleteTrailingWhitespace_Action = 'delete'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid writing the file if the file has not changed, by either using the `:update` command to do the write, or by checking the for the "modified" option in your autocmd, like `autocmd BufWritePre * if &modified | ... | endif`.